# How to find the equation of tangent using difference quotient?

Tags: calculus, functions

I have to find the equation of the tangent at $f(x)=1/x+x$ at the point $(1,2)$.

When I tried to find the slope using difference quotient, I got $0$. I am a bit confused on how to approach the problem after that point.

I think (not sure) the answer is $y-5/2= (x-2)$, but I don't know how to get it algebraically. I haven't done derivatives yet so if you could please answer this in the most basic way possible, it would be great.

Comment: That is not the answer. The slope of the function you have given is in fact zero at $(1,2)$. So either the question is wrong, the answer given is wrong, or you haven't posted it correctly.

Comment: I think the given answer is wrong. How should I approach the question to find the correct answer?

Comment: You haven't shown your work, so it's hard to say. But you have correctly found the slope. So now you are trying to find the equation of a line with a given slope going through a given point. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I use the equation y-y1=(x-x1) for finding the equation of the line. When I do that I get y-2= (x-1) which doesn't seem right when graphing.

Comment: No, you use $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$ where $m$ is the slope...

Comment: Since m is 0, the equation would be y-2=0?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: thank you so much! i was making out the problem to be more complicated that it is. thank you so much for your help!